# placement of the navigation bar for google maps

Tags: html, css, xml, google-maps, kml

Google maps by default places a navigation bar with all of your places on the left of the screen:

[image]

I was wondering if there was any way to embed something inside of the KML so that instead of having a navigation bar, I would have a key defining all the colors of the placemarks like this:

[image]

As you can see the one above is also a map, but on the bottom it has a key with all the colors.

**Is there a way to tweak the KML so that I can place some kind of KEY at the bottom of the page instead of having a navigation bar?** any guidance/advice would be most appreciated!

Comment: I don't think that is a KML thing.  You would need to write code to do that.

Comment: @geocodezip i have also asked this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12166591/creating-a-custom-layer-for-kml-file-to-be-viewed-on-mobile-devices

Comment: You wrote "how does batchgeo do this?"  Looking at [this map](http://batchgeo.com/map/1d247690af890fe6afa90e8c755f20d9) (since you didn't provide a sample link), it looks like they wrote their own parser (although their code is minimize/compiled, so it is difficult to read).

Comment: @geocodezip thank you. they wrote their own parser to create that key at the bottom? what do you mean?

Comment: That is my suspicion. That is how I have done it and seen it done, like [this map](http://creativemaps.vism.ag/)

Comment: thanks can you give me an example of how this can be done?

Comment: The one in my previous comment is the closest I have (at least that I can find quickly).  Should be pretty straightforward to modify the categories list there to a categories "bottom bar".

Comment: i'm sorry i am new to this. can you please post a detailed answer on how i can do this