# creating a custom layer for KML file to be viewed on mobile devices

Tags: xml, google-maps, mobile, maps, kml

I will need to push  about 200 KML google maps to 200 people.

The maps have each around 200-300 placemarks.

Every placemark is either, an account, potential account, or past account.

I am classifying each type of placemark with a different color pin.

I would like to know how the user can see only one type of pins at a time. I know we can do this by using `FOLDERS` , but i think a better way would be to use `LAYERS`.

The reason I think layers are better is because on mobile devices they are much easier to work with.

**Can you point me to a simple example illustrating how to use multiple layers on the same KML file that can be viewed in google maps?**

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest way to do this is to use FusionTablesLayers.  You can import your KML files, then dynamically query for the data to display and dynamically style the information.

- [FusionTableLayers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#FusionTables)
- [Dynamic Styling of FusionTableLayers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#fusion_table_styles)

You can [import KML into Fusion Tables](http://support.google.com/fusiontables/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=181717), then look at the [FusionTablesLayer Wizard](http://fusion-tables-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/FusionTablesLayerWizard/src/index.html) and/or the [FusionTablesLayer Builder](http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/fusiontables/fusiontableslayer_builder_new.html)

Comment: thanks so much. can you please show a specific example showing a KML file and inside the KML file multiple layers?

Comment: can you please give me a very simple example or find a simple example on google? i am not even sure what to google for :)

Comment: I don't know of any simple or specific examples, see the information I added to my answer.  Hopefully it will help you get started and see some of the possibilities.